# Centering two line caption in memoir

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, line-breaking

I'm struggling to center my two line captions. I'm using `memoir`  and I want the second line to be the reference to where I got the figure from.  I'm using the following code for the figure:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 16cm]{figs/123.pdf}
\caption{The Figure 123 \newline {\footnotesize \textit{Adapted from \cite{DuToit123}}} }
  \label{fig:123}
\end{figure}
```

I also included the following:

```
\captionnamefont{\small \sc}
\captionstyle[\centering]{\centering}
```

But it does not want to center both lines (I've added a screen shot of the output).

[image: Output]

Comment: They are centered, within the caption. Place the *adapted from*-part outside the caption. I bet you don't want it in your list of figures anyway.

Comment: thanx Johannes_B!! it looks much better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) accommodates the use of the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption). Then you can split out your regular `\caption` and some referencing scheme (say) `\figuresource` using `\caption*`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx,caption}

\newcommand{\figuresource}[1]{%
  \par\vspace*{-\abovecaptionskip}
  \caption*{\footnotesize\itshape #1}}

\captionsetup{
  labelfont={small,sc},
  textfont=small,
  justification=centering}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=15em]{example-image}
  \caption{The Figure 123}
  \figuresource{Adapted from ABC}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```